# FastApi get request shows validation error

Tags: python, api, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I'm getting this error when I try to get some data from my postgre db and using fastapi.

[image]

I don't know why it happens...but here is my code, thank you for your help.

**Route**

```
@router.get("/fuentes", response_model=FuenteSerializer.MFuente) # <--- WHEN I REMOVE RESPONSE_MODEL WORKS AND RETURNS A JSON DATA DIRECTLY FROM MODEL I GUESS
    async def read_fuentes(skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    fuentes = FuenteSerializer.get_fuente(db, skip=skip, limit=limit)
    return fuentes
```

**sqlalchemy model**

```
class MFuente(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'M_fuentes'

    idfuentes = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    idproductos = Column(ForeignKey('M_productos.idproductos', ondelete='RESTRICT', onupdate='RESTRICT'), index=True)
    autoapp = Column(CHAR(2))
    rutFabricante = Column(String(12))
    elemento = Column(String(100))
    estado = Column(Integer)
    stype = Column(Integer)
    aql = Column(String(5))
    equiv = Column(String(5))
    division = Column(String(100))
    nu = Column(Integer)
    filexcel = Column(String(100))

    M_producto = relationship('MProducto')
```

**Serializer / schema**

```
class MFuente(BaseModel):

    idfuentes: int
    autoapp: str
    fecregistro: datetime.date
    rutFabricante: str
    elemento: str
    estado: int
    stype: int
    aql: str
    equiv: str
    division: str
    fileexel: str
    productos: List[MProducto]

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


def get_fuente(db: Session, skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100):
   return db.query(Fuente).offset(skip).limit(limit).all()
```

Comment: My guess is that you are describing the response model as a single Fuente, while returning an array of Fuentes (or whatever that thing is). Also be sure to check the type of FuenteSerializer.get_fuente(db, skip=skip, limit=limit). If it's not of type Fuente, it cause problems

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a little debugging i created the same little prototype, and i found some possible answers.

First of all here is the app that i created:

```
class MFuente(BaseModel):
    name: str
    value: int

@app.get("/items/{name}", response_model=MFuente)
async def get_item(name: str):
    query = fuente_db.select().where(fuente_db.c.name == name)
    return await database.fetch_all(query)
```

So with this schema i get the same error

```
response -> name
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> value
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

So i debugged a little bit more i found it's all about response_model, so i came up with this:

```
from typing import List
...
@app.get("/items/{name}", response_model=List[MFuente])
```

Everything started working:

```
INFO:     127.0.0.1:52872 - "GET /items/masteryoda HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
```

So in your case fix will be:

```
@router.get("/fuentes", response_model=List[FuenteSerializer.MFuente]) 
                                       ^^^^
```